# Can't cross compile C library for arm (iOS)

Tags: ios, c, xcode, gcc, clang

I'm trying to cross-compile [libDSM](https://github.com/videolabs/libdsm) for iOS, starting with arm64.

I've pulled down the source code and have been trying to configure it using the following:

```
export XCODEDIR=$(xcode-select -p)
export DEVROOT=${XCODEDIR}/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer
export SDKROOT=$DEVROOT/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk
export CFLAGS="-arch arm64 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot $SDKROOT -mios-version-min=10.0 -I$SDKROOT/usr/include/"
export LDFLAGS="-mthumb -arch arm64 -isysroot $SDKROOT -mios-version-min=10.0"

./configure --host arm-apple-darwin --prefix $PWD/build/arm64
```

It stops with this error:

```
configure: error: C preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
```

The error in the configure.log is:

```
configure:4504: checking how to run the C preprocessor
configure:4535: gcc -E  conftest.c
In file included from conftest.c:14:
In file included from /Users/pmacro/Downloads/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.0.0/include/limits.h:37:
In file included from /Users/pmacro/Downloads/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:63:
/Users/pmacro/Downloads/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:761:2: error: Unsupported architecture
#error Unsupported architecture
 ^
```

A possibly related message earlier in configure.log is:

```
configure:3752: ./conftest

./configure: line 3754: ./conftest: Bad CPU type in executable
```

Note that it compiles fine for x86_64 (the platform I'm building on), but for any arm architecture it fails.

I've looked at examples of cross compiling for iOS and they all seem to be following these steps.  I am running pre-release software (macOS Sierra and Xcode 8), but I get the same issue when running Xcode 7 on Sierra.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: The `configure` script is running the preprocessor as `gcc -E`, and the command is failing.  The diagnostic it emits, "Unsupported architecture", comes from an `#error` directive in one of the header files being included, so one possibility is that you're somehow selecting the wrong platform SDK.  Some of the flags you're passing in `CFLAGS` look like they're really preprocessor flags, which should be in `CPPFLAGS` -- certainly `-isysroot` (which also should be in the `LDFLAGS`, as it is) and `-I`.  Maybe others, too.  Fixing that might help.

Comment: Thanks @JohnBollinger.  I figured it out just now - I needed to specify the architecture (-arch arm64) in CPPFLAGS as well as CFLAGS.  Thanks for those other suggestions, too.  I'll take a look at those and tidy things up.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was that I needed to specify the architecture (-arch arm64) in CPPFLAGS as well as CFLAGS.