# Convert library.a for macOSX to library.a for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there a way to convert a library that is built for macOS to a library that I can use in my iOS project. I'm getting an error in my app that follows:

```
/Users/edwardpizzurro/Desktop/LibreriasAlternativas/LibreriasAlternativas.xcodeproj Building for iOS, but the linked library 'libsndfile.a' was built for macOS.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it's not possible and you have to rebuild your library specifying iOS architecture.

To get more info about your library, run

```
lipo -info libsndfile.a
```

It'll give you architectures like `armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64 arm64`. A default architecture for iOS is `arm64`, while for MacOS it's `x86_64` (we are not speaking of new M1 hardware). So most probably for your `libsndfile.a` you'll get only `x86_64`.

This will mean you need to build libsndfile by yourself.

Here are releases of this lib, there's no `arm64` here: https://github.com/libsndfile/libsndfile/releases

So you have to donwload the repo: https://github.com/libsndfile/libsndfile
And use smth like Autotools to build it for your desired architecture.

A rough example of what you'll have to do it here: [Can't cross compile C library for arm (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836754/cant-cross-compile-c-library-for-arm-ios)

While it's quite specific for each library.