# Cannot cross-compile static C library for iPhone (arm64) on macOS (x86_64)

Tags: ios, macos, cross-compiling

I've been trying to cross-compile a static C library for use in an iOS application. 
I figured that this can be achieved by wrapping the headers and binaries in an XCFramework, but the compiled library is for an x86_64 architecture, so it can't run on iOS.

What I did was the following:

```
export IOS_SDK_LOC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk
export AARCH64_FLAGS="-arch arm64 -isysroot $IOS_SDK_LOC "

./configure --host=arm_apple_darwin --build=x86_64_apple_darwin --target=x86_64_apple_darwin
          \ CFLAGS=$AARCH64_FLAGS CPPFLAGS=$AARCH64_FLAGS
```

I initially tried to just have the CFLAGS, but ended up passing the same arguments as CPPFLAGS as well following the answer at [Can't cross compile C library for arm (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836754/cant-cross-compile-c-library-for-arm-ios)

In either case, I get the same error:
`configure: error: cannot run test program while cross compiling`

How should I go about compiling my library in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I found for compiling an arm64 static library on the same machine was to **install QEMU** (machine emulator), with the target OS in mind.

As luck would have it, Jonathan Afek from Aleph Security recently wrote a frame buffer for iOS QEMU, making it particularly easy to work with now.

More information here: https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/kxr0v8/news_ios_qemu_is_getting_a_graphical_display_ios/